# Ionic-2 : Space issue between ion-items

Tags: ionic2

I'm using 'ngFor' to repeat ion-items but i'm not getting any space b/w each item.

[image]

My code :

```
<ion-list >
    <button ion-item class="my-item" *ngFor="let r of recentUpdatesData" (click)="goToReleatedPage(r)">
        <ion-thumbnail item-left>
            <img src="assets/{{r.imagePath}}" alt="your image">
        </ion-thumbnail>
        <h2><strong>{{r.title}}</strong></h2>
        <h3>{{r.type}}</h3>
        <p>{{r.description | slice : 0:500}}</p>
    </button>
    <hr class="style14" />
</ion-list>
```

Final result i need:

[image: Final result i need]

Comment: I dont understand.. You need space or not? the images show otherwise

Comment: i need result as show in fig.2 with spacing b/w items.

Comment: what if you use ion-item instead of button? all the padding seems to be because of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use just `ion-item` instead of `button`. It seems to be adding additional padding to the list item.

```
<ion-list >
    <ion-item class="my-item" *ngFor="let r of recentUpdatesData" (tap)="goToReleatedPage(r)">
        <ion-thumbnail item-left>
            <img src="assets/{{r.imagePath}}" alt="your image">
        </ion-thumbnail>
        <h2><strong>{{r.title}}</strong></h2>
        <h3>{{r.type}}</h3>
        <p>{{r.description | slice : 0:500}}</p>
    </ion-item>
    <hr class="style14" />
</ion-list>
```

Side note: use `tap` instead of `click` in mobile devices.

Or you should redesign using [`ion-grid`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#grid) instead of ion-list.

```
 <ion-grid>
        <ion-row class="my-item" *ngFor="let r of recentUpdatesData" (tap)="goToReleatedPage(r)">
          <ion-col col-6>
            <ion-thumbnail item-left>
                <img src="assets/{{r.imagePath}}" alt="your image">
            </ion-thumbnail>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col>
             <ion-row>
            <h2><strong>{{r.title}}</strong></h2>
             </ion-row>
            <ion-row>
            <h3>{{r.type}}</h3>
             </ion-row>
             <ion-row>
            <p>{{r.description | slice : 0:500}}</p>
</ion-row>
</ion-col>

        </ion-row>
        <hr class="style14" />
    </ion-grid>
```

Comment: And any change?

Comment: Or you should redesign using [`ion-grid`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#grid) instead of ion-item

Comment: ion-grid in place of ion item?  ok i will try.

Comment: design has totally changed. I'm getting Image then h2,h3, and description.

Comment: You need set the col width according to how you need if you go with grid..

Comment: as u suggested i changed my code(ion-item to ion-grid) and now i got the result thank you so much.

Comment: glad it worked :) consider marking it as solved.. will help anyone else with the issue